# How to get average score of K-Fold cross validation with sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation

I apply decision tree with K-fold using sklearn and someone can help me to show the average score of it. Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,classification_report

dta=pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/blood-transfusion/transfusion.data")

X=dta.drop("whether he/she donated blood in March 2007",axis=1)

X=X.values # convert dataframe to numpy array

y=dta["whether he/she donated blood in March 2007"]

y=y.values # convert dataframe to numpy array

kf = KFold(n_splits=10)

KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=None, shuffle=False)

clf_tree=DecisionTreeClassifier()

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    clf=clf_tree.fit(X_train,y_train)
    print("classification_report_tree", 
           classification_report(y_test,clf_tree.predict(X_test)))
```

Comment: What do you mean by `average score`? Do you only want the accuracy ? Or the recall, precision and f1 also (as you are printing the classification report).

Comment: I want to run decision tree with K Fold and show overall accuracy, with k fold is 10 that will run 10 times and give us 10 accuracy each running time. How to show overall accuracy of training

Answer (score 6):

If you only want accuracy, then you can simply use [`cross_val_score()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html)

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=10)
clf_tree=DecisionTreeClassifier()
scores = cross_val_score(clf_tree, X, y, cv=kf)

avg_score = np.mean(score_array)
print(avg_score)
```

Here `cross_val_score` will take as input your original X and y (without splitting into train and test). `cross_val_score` will automatically split them into train and test, fit the model on train data and score on test data. And those scores will be returned in the `scores` variable.

So when you have 10 folds, 10 scores will be returned in `scores` variable. You can then just take an average of that.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [Precision_recall_fscore_support](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html#sklearn-metrics-precision-recall-fscore-support) metric from sklearn and then get average the results for each fold per class. I am assuming here that you need the scores average per class.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV,cross_val_score

dta=pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/blood-transfusion/transfusion.data")

X=dta.drop("whether he/she donated blood in March 2007",axis=1)

X=X.values # convert dataframe to numpy array

y=dta["whether he/she donated blood in March 2007"]

y=y.values # convert dataframe to numpy array

kf = KFold(n_splits=10)

KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=None, shuffle=False)

clf_tree=DecisionTreeClassifier()

score_array =[]
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    clf=clf_tree.fit(X_train,y_train)
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    score_array.append(precision_recall_fscore_support(y_test, y_pred, average=None))

avg_score = np.mean(score_array,axis=0)
print(avg_score)

#Output:
#[[  0.77302466   0.30042282]
# [  0.81755068   0.22192344]
# [  0.79063779   0.24414489]
# [ 57.          17.8       ]]
```

Now to get precision of class 0, you can use `avg_score[0][0]`. The recall can be accessed by the second row (i.e. for class 0, it is `avg_score[1][0]`), while the fscore and support can be accessed from 3rd and 4th row respectively.

Comment: while the other answer is technically correct, this answer also shows how to actually train the model! :)